Function to convert a pandas dataframe into JSON
I have a pandas dataframe that I want to convert to JSON in the required format. The JSON is basically a tree structure of the dataframe.
Input:
Total           Resolution  Category    Escalated   Count
Total Tickets   False       IT          False       4
Total Tickets   False       IT          True        3
Total Tickets   True        IT          False       1
Total Tickets   True        IT          True        15
Total Tickets   True        Unknown     True        1

Current Output:
{
    "chart":
    {
        "data":
        {
            "path":
            [],
            "displayColumnLabel": "Total",
            "displayValueLabel": "Total Tickets",
            "values":
            [
                {
                    "type": "ticket",
                    "value": 24,
                    "change": 0,
                    "changeType": "neutral"
                }
            ],
            "isCritial": false,
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "path":
                    [],
                    "displayColumnLabel": "Resolution",
                    "displayValueLabel": "True",
                    "values":
                    [
                        {
                            "type": "ticket",
                            "value": 17,
                            "change": 0,
                            "changeType": "neutral"
                        }
                    ],
                    "isCritial": false,
                    "children":
                    [
                        {
                            "path":
                            [],
                            "displayColumnLabel": "Category",
                            "displayValueLabel": "IT",
                            "values":
                            [
                                {
                                    "type": "ticket",
                                    "value": 16,
                                    "change": 0,
                                    "changeType": "neutral"
                                }
                            ],
                            "isCritial": false,
                            "children":
                            [
                                {
                                    "path":
                                    [],
                                    "displayColumnLabel": "Escalated",
                                    "displayValueLabel": "True",
                                    "values":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "type": "ticket",
                                            "value": 15,
                                            "change": 0,
                                            "changeType": "neutral"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "isCritial": false,
                                    "children":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "path":
                                            [],
                                            "displayColumnLabel": "tickets",
                                            "displayValueLabel": "15",
                                            "values":
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "ticket",
                                                    "value": 15,
                                                    "change": 0,
                                                    "changeType": "neutral"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "isCritial": false,
                                            "children":
                                            []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "path":
                                    [],
                                    "displayColumnLabel": "Escalated",
                                    "displayValueLabel": "False",
                                    "values":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "type": "ticket",
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "change": 0,
                                            "changeType": "neutral"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "isCritial": false,
                                    "children":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "path":
                                            [],
                                            "displayColumnLabel": "tickets",
                                            "displayValueLabel": "1",
                                            "values":
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "ticket",
                                                    "value": 1,
                                                    "change": 0,
                                                    "changeType": "neutral"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "isCritial": false,
                                            "children":
                                            []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "path":
                            [],
                            "displayColumnLabel": "Category",
                            "displayValueLabel": "Unknown",
                            "values":
                            [
                                {
                                    "type": "ticket",
                                    "value": 1,
                                    "change": 0,
                                    "changeType": "neutral"
                                }
                            ],
                            "isCritial": false,
                            "children":
                            [
                                {
                                    "path":
                                    [],
                                    "displayColumnLabel": "Escalated",
                                    "displayValueLabel": "True",
                                    "values":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "type": "ticket",
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "change": 0,
                                            "changeType": "neutral"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "isCritial": false,
                                    "children":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "path":
                                            [],
                                            "displayColumnLabel": "tickets",
                                            "displayValueLabel": "1",
                                            "values":
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "ticket",
                                                    "value": 1,
                                                    "change": 0,
                                                    "changeType": "neutral"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "isCritial": false,
                                            "children":
                                            []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "path":
                    [],
                    "displayColumnLabel": "Resolution",
                    "displayValueLabel": "False",
                    "values":
                    [
                        {
                            "type": "ticket",
                            "value": 7,
                            "change": 0,
                            "changeType": "neutral"
                        }
                    ],
                    "isCritial": false,
                    "children":
                    [
                        {
                            "path":
                            [],
                            "displayColumnLabel": "Category",
                            "displayValueLabel": "IT",
                            "values":
                            [
                                {
                                    "type": "ticket",
                                    "value": 7,
                                    "change": 0,
                                    "changeType": "neutral"
                                }
                            ],
                            "isCritial": false,
                            "children":
                            [
                                {
                                    "path":
                                    [],
                                    "displayColumnLabel": "Escalated",
                                    "displayValueLabel": "False",
                                    "values":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "type": "ticket",
                                            "value": 4,
                                            "change": 0,
                                            "changeType": "neutral"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "isCritial": false,
                                    "children":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "path":
                                            [],
                                            "displayColumnLabel": "tickets",
                                            "displayValueLabel": "4",
                                            "values":
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "ticket",
                                                    "value": 4,
                                                    "change": 0,
                                                    "changeType": "neutral"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "isCritial": false,
                                            "children":
                                            []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "path":
                                    [],
                                    "displayColumnLabel": "Escalated",
                                    "displayValueLabel": "True",
                                    "values":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "type": "ticket",
                                            "value": 3,
                                            "change": 0,
                                            "changeType": "neutral"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "isCritial": false,
                                    "children":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "path":
                                            [],
                                            "displayColumnLabel": "tickets",
                                            "displayValueLabel": "3",
                                            "values":
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "ticket",
                                                    "value": 3,
                                                    "change": 0,
                                                    "changeType": "neutral"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "isCritial": false,
                                            "children":
                                            []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Problem:
My current function works, but there are two things I cant figure out.

'path' is always [], the logic for path is that for root node path=[], and for the child nodes it follows the parent node path. Eg: for 2nd Node, path:[Total Tickets]
'isCritial' (typo is intentional) flag, basically this flag is true for all nodes specified by the user. eg: the row with count 15 is deemed target and all nodes(Total:Total Tickets, Resolution:True, Category:IT, Escalated:True, Count:15)

Current function:
def create_hierarchical_json_new(df, value_column='Ticket Id'):
    # Extract column names
    columns = df.columns.tolist()
    

    # Build data and children sections
    def build_children(df, group_cols):
        if not group_cols:
            return []  # Base case: no more grouping columns, return empty list

        current_col = group_cols[0]
        grouped = df.groupby(current_col)
        children = []
        for value, group in grouped:
            is_terminal_node = len(group_cols) == 1
            child = {
                "path": [],
                "displayColumnLabel": current_col,
                "displayValueLabel": str(value),
                "values": [
                    {
                        "type": "ticket",
                        "value": group[value_column].sum(),
                        "change": 0,
                        "changeType": "neutral",
                    }
                ],
                "isCritial": False,
                "children": build_children(group, group_cols[1:]),
            }

            # Add one more node if this is the terminal node
            if is_terminal_node:
                child["children"].append({
                    "path": [],
                    "displayColumnLabel": "tickets",
                    "displayValueLabel": str(group[value_column].sum()),
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "type": "ticket",
                            "value": group[value_column].sum(),
                            "change": 0,
                            "changeType": "neutral",
                        }
                    ],
                    "isCritial": False,
                    "children": []
                })

            children.append(child)
        return children

    data = {
        "path": [],
        "displayColumnLabel": columns[0],
        "displayValueLabel": str(df[columns[0]].iloc[0]),
        "values": [
            {
                "type": "ticket",
                "value": df[value_column].sum(),
                "change": 0,
                "changeType": "neutral",
            }
        ],
        "isCritial": False,
        "children": build_children(df, columns[1:-1]),  # Group by all columns except first and last
    }

    # Combine meta and data sections
    result = {
        "chart": {
            "data": data
        }
    }

    return result


To make it easier for us to troubleshoot your problem, please provide your input as code that when executed creates a (toy) dataframe for input (rather than the output of displaying the dataframe) and also provide not just your current output but the desired output as well.

Could you please provide the correct json result you need? I didn't quite understand the JSON format you're talking about. Like what decides a child? I thought some rows are children of another row, but from the json output you've provided, it seems that's not the case.

Why are you defining a function inside another function?

So read the pivot table, the right most column is the root node (common across all rows), then the next column are the two child nodes (resolution=true and resolution=false) so on. Each tree will terminate at the last column where the leaf value will be 4,3,15, 1. @eternal_white

Dude, with all the respect. This explanation doesn't clarify much. What do you mean by the right most column is the root node? a whole column is a node? As said, if you could provide the desired json result it'd be much better than ambiguously describing the structure you want.
